# Safari cannot debug my Ionic application, specifically cannot explore 'main.js' file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, safari

Until recently, I could use Safari from my Mac Powerbook to debug my Ionic 4 application running on my iPhone.

Now, I can still connect and see the project/files, but I cannot expand the 'main.js' in the 'resources' tab. When I expand it, it appears empty.

I *can* see the transpiled .js files in the debug tab, but these are arcane and not very useful.

I am hoping this is simply a mapping file not getting passed up.

My stack is:
Ionic 3.9.2
Cordova 8.1.2
Cordova - iOS platform 4.5.5
Node 6.11.0
phone-iOS 12.3.1
PowerMac-iOS 10.14.5

I tried updating versions of cordova/cordova-platforms/ionic/iOS (on workstation).
I have tried with Safari Technology Preview to no avail either.

I tried installing 'ionic-webview' which gave me visibility to 'main.js' file, I could explore it. But my app creates a critical new window (using Wikitude AR), and this window freezes all activity in the parent that spawned it. This breaks functionality.

Ionic-webview uses 'wkwebview', which would explain this. There are many complaints about wkwebview and child windows communicating with parent.

I uninstalled ionic-webview, now my app works, but I have no way to use the nice mapped 'main.js' for debugging. This makes development very tough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use live reload in ionic and inspect in the safari developer options.You can test your app work flow using live reload.